# How to change c++ version in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, c++17, c++23

I've used C++17 in VS Code. Now I want to use C++20 or C++23, but I can't change from the C++17 version.

I've tried many ways, like adding "-std-c++2b" in Task.json or setting C++Standard to C++23, but my VS Code is still in C++17. Maybe I reinstalled VS Code and set it again?

Comment: Which plugin are you using to compile your code? Can you show the compile output with the compile command line?

Answer (score 1):

In the VSCode project browse the `.vscode` folder and in the `tasks.json` type something like this (adapt it to your needs regarding the version):

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-std=c++23"  // Add this line for C++23
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Also try to configure the `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++23"  // Change this line for C++23
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Finally rebuild your project. It should work for you.